# React Native: No dimension set for key window in production

Tags: react-native

I'm getting this error

`RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: No dimension set for key windowmh_execute_header
Unhandled JS Exception: No dimension set for key window, stack: value@75:505`

in production. I believe that it's an issue with RN: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13758

All of the solutions in that thread look like they are for the development environment. Is there a way to fix this for production (after uploading a new build of course)?

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@yfuks/react-native-action-sheet": "latest",
    "bugsnag-react-native": "^2.2.3",
    "iap-receipt-validator": "^1.0.6",
    "js-uuid": "^0.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "phoenix": "^1.2.1",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "0.44.0",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-aws3": "^0.0.8",
    "react-native-code-push": "^2.0.3-beta",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-elevated-view": "^0.0.3",
    "react-native-firestack": "^2.3.9",
    "react-native-flags": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-geocoder": "^0.4.8",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.1",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-in-app-utils": "^5.2.3",
    "react-native-incall-manager": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-keep-awake": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "latest",
    "react-native-localization": "^0.1.30",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^1.3.9",
    "react-native-permissions": "^0.2.7",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-spinkit": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-webrtc": "^1.57.0",
    "react-native-zzy-toast": "^0.1.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.8.2",
    "redux-observable": "^0.14.1",
    "redux-persist": "^4.5.0",
    "rn-splash-screen": "^4.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.2.0"
  },
```

Comment: Hi @Edmund, have same issue, did you fix this?

Comment: Couldn't fix it... I think it's a react native thing

Comment: I am having the same issue on a new react-native project

Answer (score 0):

If have you installed react-native-router-flux 3.38.0 after removing "^" from dependencies?

Comment: I'm not using react router flux. It's not in my package.json

Comment: can you share your package.json file